# Quotes within php quote

Tags: php

I put quotes around my "name" within my php header for sending email. But it gives me php error when doing so.

> $headers   = "From: **"name"** " . "\r\n";

How can i get that to work with quotes around name?

I tried 'name' but it doesnt work when i get an email it shows my server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is deeply discussed in any b asic tutorial of almost any programming language

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quotes with a backslash:

```
$headers = "From: \"name\" " . "\r\n";
```

For more information on possible escapes [refer to the PHP manual on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Another solution would be using single quoted strings, as you don't have any variables or other escapes in there:

```
$headers = 'From: "name" ' . "\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes:

```
$headers = 'FROM: "name"' . "\r\n";
```

Or you can use double quotes with escaping:

```
$headers = "FROM : \"name\"\r\n";
```

Or you can use [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax:

```
$headers = <<<TEXT
FROM: "name"
TEXT;
```

Please read the [documentation article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).